# What is this type of diagram called?

Tags: research

## The context

I was reading [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7439) in Arxiv "The OpenPicoAmp : an open-source planar lipid bilayer amplifier for hands-on learning of neuroscience" ([PDF available here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7439.pdf)) and found two diagrams.

[image]

I know the type of diagrams for (B) are called "circuit diagrams", but I don't know what's the name for the type of diagram of (A). Both (A) and (B) use a buffer amplifier, but I wonder if there's a common name for the type of diagram of (A).

## The question

Is there a common name for the type of diagram of (A)? If not, what's the name of the blue part called? (If I recall correctly, the red part is called "buffer amplifier")

[image]

Comment: a cross section?

Comment: Both A & B are circuit diagrams. The difference is that "B" is a closed loop circuit, while the circuit of "A" is connected through the liquid conductor.

Comment: neither are called graphs.  A is a circuit diagram with details

Comment: Figure B would typically be called a **schematic** diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The type of diagram in blue is a "pictorial diagram" or "pictorial circuit diagram." Figure A a combination of a pictorial diagram and a "schematic diagram" or "schematic circuit diagram."

The part shown in figure A is referred to in the paper as a "bilayer chamber." It is a experimental apparatus used to measure the electrical properties of a lipid bilayer. It is not a standard component so there is no standard schematic diagram element for it. The component behaves similarly to a resistor and a capacitor in parallel, so the authors draw it that way in figure B.